# Mimic another website - video gallery

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, video

I'm trying to create a similar sub domain for my website for videos -http://media.futuremoneytrends.com/index.html

The main website (https://www.futuremoneytrends.com/) is made with wordpress, and it seems this media version is made with bootstrap.

Realistically, I could make this with bootstrap and some custom code and what not, but the tricky thing is that my employer needs a simple CMS to use like WordPress to add video's, but as I've been trying to make one, its notoriously hard to manage to create nice video layout that will function in a similar function as youtube, or more specifically the media.futuremoneytrends.com website.

So knowing that this subdomain is made with bootstrap, and the main domain is made with wordpress, I found some resources online that I can link up my two website to use the same database. Therefore, he can still use the same website and the video's will be uploaded to bootstrap.

> Now the coding question

After all that background knowledge, how would I pull information from a wordpress CMS with a website that DOES NOT use wordpress at all (my custom subdomain)? I can't wrap my head around how to do it?

As I think this is one of the only routes I can think of. If there is another alternative I should consider, like possibly just creating a custom php CMS being an easier route, I'll consider that.

Any related resources would be incredibly useful.

Comment: sigh, why the down vote? too broad of a question?

Comment: I didn't down vote you but I think your question is not related to or have any coding related issue. Its more like a general spy question

Comment: I'll edit the question some more.

Comment: It's probable that the site you've linked to uses a WordPress plugin for the videos, can you not rummage the source code to find the plugin and then just download and install that?

Comment: There is no plugin, I've been dissecting this website as much as I can and I don't see anything WordPress related to it at all. That's what boggles my mind. BUT, on his main website, the video's from there to here are defiantly linked.

Comment: Have you considered accessing the Wordpress database directly from the other app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a cookie called `melody_device`. It is highly probable that they are using PHP Melody CMD.

This site shows all the site with that cookie

> https://webcookies.org/cookie/http/melody_device/15429

Fururemonethrends site cookie

```
Cookie:PHPSESSID=fe860147400ae982c02c2e850d16ec18; melody_device=desktop; _gat=1; watched_video_list=MjI0Mw%3D%3D; pm_elastic_player=normal; jwplayer.captionLabel=Off; _ga=GA1.2.1834527991.1467232624
```

PHP Melody demo (http://demo.phpmelody.com/) site cookie

> PHPSESSID=25940fd188e3efe7aca4d0a2bc522e90; melody_device=desktop; __utmt=1; __utma=115875527.781292918.1467233438.1467233438.1467233438.1; __utmb=115875527.1.10.1467233438; __utmc=115875527; __utmz=115875527.1467233438.1.1.utmcsr=phpsugar.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/phpmelody_demo.html; melody_pad_7ece56d7834bced47d7261955cdf94cd=7ece56d7834b; jwplayer.captionLabel=Off

Which is pretty much the same..

Comment: This is glorious, I wasn't aware that this type of CMS even excisted... THANK YOU!

Comment: You can see the header of the request from google chrome developer tools,. or you can use curl or wget with cookie enabled